# how to give space in between user icon and User name in material UI?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm new to material UI, i've created a User icon and User name but i couldn't able to give space in between them. I've tried by giving p={1} and m={1} but didn't worked.
Can anyone assist me how to give space in between them?

```
import React from "react";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import Menu from "@material-ui/core/Menu";
import MenuItem from "@material-ui/core/MenuItem";
import Avatar from "@material-ui/core/Avatar";
import Fade from "@material-ui/core/Fade";

export default function FadeMenu() {
  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = React.useState(null);
  const open = Boolean(anchorEl);

  const handleClick = event => {
    setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    setAnchorEl(null);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Button

        aria-controls="fade-menu"
        aria-haspopup="true"
        onClick={handleClick}
      >
        <Avatar mx="auto">AJ</Avatar>
        Anthony Johnson
      </Button>

      <Menu
        id="fade-menu"
        anchorEl={anchorEl}
        keepMounted
        open={open}
        onClose={handleClose}
        TransitionComponent={Fade}
      >
        <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>Profile</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>My account</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>Logout</MenuItem>
      </Menu>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is the Code: "https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-7vvuy"

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with a solution

```js
import React from "react";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import Menu from "@material-ui/core/Menu";
import MenuItem from "@material-ui/core/MenuItem";
import Avatar from "@material-ui/core/Avatar";
import Fade from "@material-ui/core/Fade";

const styles = () => ({
  avatar: {
    marginRight: 15
  }
});

export default function FadeMenu() {
  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = React.useState(null);
  const open = Boolean(anchorEl);
  const {classes} = this.props;

  const handleClick = event => {
    setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    setAnchorEl(null);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Button

        aria-controls="fade-menu"
        aria-haspopup="true"
        onClick={handleClick}
      >
        <Avatar mx="auto" className={classes.avatar}>AJ</Avatar>
        Anthony Johnson
      </Button>

      <Menu
        id="fade-menu"
        anchorEl={anchorEl}
        keepMounted
        open={open}
        onClose={handleClose}
        TransitionComponent={Fade}
      >
        <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>Profile</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>My account</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>Logout</MenuItem>
      </Menu>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Use `className` and pass classes as props.

For reference please use https://material-ui.com/api/avatar/